# Convert datetime (e.g. 01JAN2020) to date format (e.g 01/01/2020) in SAS

Tags: date, sas, formatting

I have a bunch of datetime formatted values in my dateset that started in the format 01JAN2020:00:00:00. I've managed to condense this down using dtdate9. but that changes the format to 01JAN20. I'm looking to change the format to 01/01/2020, any ideas?

Comment: Do you just want to change how the value is displayed (that is what a FORMAT does)? Or do you want to convert the datetime value (# of seconds) into a date value (# of days)? Is 01/01/2020 in MDY order of DMY order?

Comment: Would you want 01Jan2020 or 01Jan20? 01Jan020 is an uncommon request.

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo. In the example, I'm looking to change it from 01JAN20 to 01/01/2020

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no off the shelf SAS format that maps a datetime value to construct *mm/dd/yyyy*.

You can create a user defined function with `FCMP` that computes the transform and specify that function in a custom format.

Example:

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.functions.formats;
  function dtmmddyy(datetime) $10;
    return (put(datepart(datetime), mmddyy10.));
  endsub;
run;

proc format;
  value dtmmddyy
    low-high = [dtmmddyy()]
  ;
run;

options cmplib=(work.functions);

data _null_;
  dt = input ('01JAN2020:00:00:00', datetime20.);
  put 
    dt= dtdate9. /
    dt= dtmmddyy. /
  ;

run;
```

Log

```
dt=01JAN2020
dt=01/01/2020
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom datetime type format like this

```
proc format; 
  picture dtdmy (default=10)
    low - high = '%D/%0m/%Y' (datatype=datetime)
  ;
run;

data _null_;
   dt = '01JAN2020:00:00:00'dt;
   put dt = dtdate9.;
   put dt = dtdmy.;
run;
```

Comment: Excellent reminder of `Proc FORMAT` power and DMY Euro flair !

Comment: @Richard Thanks. Proc Format is one of my absolute favorites. Part of the reason is the functionality that you demonstrate nicely in your reply. Being able to use function logic in formats makes it so flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You can also control it via the length on a date time format, especially if it's only for display, at least if it's MDY. Not sure about DMY formats.

```
data demo;
have = dhms('01Jan2020'd, 4, 3, 0);
x = have;
format x mdyampm10. have datetime22.;
run;
```

> 1 01JAN2020:04:03:00  **1/1/20**